# How to cascade many-to-one association in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am a bit confused about something right now about hibernate property. I have a parent class that doesn't need to browse its child for now, eg the type of table that just holds information (id| currency | description)
so in the mapping file of the parent, I ignore the set tag.
in the child class, I have reference to the parent (the parent object property) and had a many-to-one tag

```
<class name="parent">
  <id name="id">
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="currency"/>
  <property name="description" length="400">
</class>
```

Here is the child mapping file

```
<class name="child">
  <id name="id">
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="someprop1"/>
  <property name="someprop2">
  <many-to-one class="Parent" column="parent_field" name="parent" />
</class>
```

That's it but it seems to me that the child is trying to save to the parent what I don't want to allow so I'm wondering if I should use inverse true here or cascade.using the cascade on the many-to-one association looks like it's meant for the child to insert or delete from the parent. Unless I'm really confused.so my only concern, for now, is to prevent the child to insert in the parent.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: As your mapping is written, calling **Session.save** on the child should not cause Hibernate to try to save the parent. You would have to put a cascade attribute on the **many-to-one** element to get that behavior. What's leading you to believe otherwise?

Comment: ok atuaclly there are other class involve in the process, but here is a fair example of what i was doing.supposing i want to insert in the child table, i call a method on the parentDao getByCurrency() for example to have a parent object which i set to the child setParent property before i save the child.i get j Duplicate entry error.that's why i was wondering

Comment: I'm sorry, but this description still doesn't provide enough info to diagnose the problem. If you could post your code and the exact exception you're getting, that might help.